# Remove accents from characters

Tags: text-processing

I'm quite certain this has been asked and answered before, however, I cannot find the answer to my specific use-case.

I've got this file with accented characters in it:

```bsh
>  ~ cat file
ë
ê
Ý,text
Ò
É
```

How would I convert them to their respective non-accented letters? So the outcome would be something along the lines of:

```bsh
> ~ convert file out.txt
> ~ cat out.txt
e
e
Y,text
O
E
```

Note that the actual file itself contains more characters.

Comment: Those look like accented letters to me: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic Of course, if you need to change some other symbols to letters too, by some rule, then that's different.

Comment: Would you change ü to ue (German equivalents) or plain u? Even in English, how would you expect to map æ?

Comment: Your first example is not an accent but a diaeresis. Do you want to convert those, too? Your question is self-contradictory in that regard.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can try `iconv`, with the `//TRANSLIT` (transliteration) option

Ex. given

```
$ cat file
ë
ê
Ý,text
Ò
É
```

then

```
$ iconv -t ASCII//TRANSLIT file
e
e
Y,text
O
E
```

Comment: doesn't work on my mac. but works on CentOS 8. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinC I wonder if it would work on the mac if you added an appropriate `-f` value to specify the input encoding? Perhaps obtained using the `file` command on your input file?

Comment: Do you have the same `iconv` on both systems?

Comment: `echo mówił, że | iconv -t ASCII//TRANSLIT` => `mowiiconv: illegal input sequence at position 5`

Comment: @UncleBilly Works fine for me.  (macOS 10.14.6, `iconv (GNU libiconv 1.11)`, Terminal text encoding = `Unicode (UTF-8)`.)

Comment: @gidds It looks that the problem is with the `C.UTF-8` locale, at least on Debian 10. I didn't expect `iconv` to care about the locales when both `-f` and `-t` are used, but it does: `echo mówił, że | LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8 iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//translit` => `illegal input sequence at position 5` (`iconv (Debian GLIBC 2.28-10) 2.28`)

Comment: @UncleBilly That command woks fine on macOS, too.  (And with LC_CTYPE set to `C`, `POSIX`, `ASCII`, `en.ASCII`, `UTF-8`, `en_US.UTF-8`, `ISO8859-1`, `en_US.ISO8859-1`…  Also with LC_CTYPE exported first so it applies to the `echo` — in non-UTF cases those chars appear as hex codes on the command line, but `iconv` still converts them to the equivalent ASCII.)

Comment: @gidds yes, it looks like a bug (feature?) in glibc (the default C library on linux) -- it also happens with the `iconv(3)` library function, not just with the `iconv` utility.

Comment: I wonder why it didn't work for Kevin C, then…

Comment: Very useful answer, thanks !! But I am disappointed when I look at the `iconv(1)` man page. It does not say anything about `ascii//TRANSLIT`. And `iconv --list` does not mention `TRANSLIT`. How can one find all these options for encodings ?

Comment: @phs it should be part of the description of `-t` or `--to-code=` option: *"If  the  string //TRANSLIT is appended to to-encoding, characters being converted are transliterated when needed and possible."*

Comment: I don't get the same behavior:
`echo 'ÉÀîéàç' | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ASCII//TRANSLIT` returns
```'E`A^i'e`ac```.
My problem here is i don't want the quotes in the output (i know i may pipe it through `tr -d` but it would remove the actual quotes from the original text)

Answer (score 8):

The GNU recode package is very useful to convert between character encodings, and it has a special case that does exactly this with the "flat" encoding:

```
recode -f utf8..flat <textin.txt >flattext.out
```