# sed letter change for non-english letters?

Tags: bash, sed

I want to convert my languages letters to english equalevent. It should be something like this:

```
echo "İığüşöç" | <sed command>
Iigusoc
```

How can i do it?
EDIT:
And i realize, i want to make uppercase all.

Here's my code

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "İlçe seçin"
read n | <a command can make convert to english equalevent and make uppercase>                 
sonuc=$(w3m http://www.koeri.boun.edu.tr/scripts/lst5.asp | grep $n)
echo "$sonuc"
```

Comment: Sed does not seem to be the right tool for this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207354/how-to-remove-all-of-the-diacritics-from-a-file

Comment: Thanks. But i want on-single-line command :)

Comment: @LinuxAndBash Why would you ever want a single line command to do a complicated task? Write a script and call that. That's your single line command.

Comment: Ah nevermind. Can we edit for the last .sh command ?

Comment: The `sed` command for this would be `y` like in `sed 'y/çğİıöşü/CGIIOSU/'`, but this requires all your desired replacements to be specified manually. For standard replacements, see `iconv`

Comment: Not technically a duplicate if you need to do it with sed etc., but here's an answer with `iconv`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/631652/170373 (There's also the discussion on what counts as an English letter, but I suppose you wanted to just map everything to the nearest equivalent from the 26 ASCII letters.)

Comment: Thank you my dear friend :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'İığüşöç' | iconv -t ASCII//TRANSLIT
Iigusoc
```

works on some systems (`//TRANSLIT` is from Solaris I believe but is also supported on GNU systems).

In locales using UTF-8 as charmap, you can also use:

```
$ locale charmap
UTF-8
$ printf '%s\n' 'İığüşöç' | uconv -x Latin-ASCII
Iigusoc
```

See also GNU `recode`'s:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'İığüşöç' | recode ..ascii
Iig"us"oc
```

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'İığüşöç' | recode -f ..flat
Iigusoc
```

With `sed` implementations that support character equivalence in regexps and with `zsh`:

```
$ printf -v sed_script 's/[[=%s=]]/%1$s/g\n' {a..z}
$ printf '%s\n' 'İığüşöç' | sed $sed_script
iıgusoc
```

(there `ı` is not considered to be in the same equivalent class as `i` or `I` though).

Comment: Thank you! `$ printf '%s\n' 'İığüşöç' | uconv -x Latin-ASCII` worked perfectly for me :)